# Adding to new array if key in multiarray check

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array `$items` and I need to search it and then create new array(s).

This array is generated at the end of check-up in e-shop I'm trying to build, so array can be of random length. I need to create to create new array for every new `supplier_id` so I can send data to each and every one of them apart.

I already have code for making order but now it just takes all data at once. So in this particular example I'm expecting 3 multidimensional arrays that I can run trough my `create_order` code.

I know there are many threads talking about multidimensional arrays but none that I can understand enough to apply it in my case. Thanks very much for help.

Here is what `$items` may look like

```
array (4)
    id => 36
    count => 1
    product => Nette\Database\Table\ActiveRow #7c60
        table private => Nette\Database\Table\Selection #739c
        data private => array (3)
            product_id => 36
            price => 219.0
            supplier_id => 3
        dataRefreshed private => FALSE
    names => array (1)
        en => "Product 1" (9)
array (4)
    id => 180
    count => 1
    product => Nette\Database\Table\ActiveRow #938b
        table private => Nette\Database\Table\Selection #a5f0
        data private => array (3)
            product_id => 180
            price => 375.0
            supplier_id => 4
        dataRefreshed private => FALSE
    names => array (1)
        en => "Product 2" (9)
array (4)
    id => 309
    count => 1
    product => Nette\Database\Table\ActiveRow #4c67
        table private => Nette\Database\Table\Selection #8f56
        data private => array (3)
            product_id => 309
            price => 40.0
            supplier_id => 5
        dataRefreshed private => FALSE
    names => array (1)
        en => "Product 3" (9)
```

Comment: The problem, can you describe it?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please show your output of the array with `var_export`!  On SO should always post data with `var_export` so people here can better work with that. Btw: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am afraid this looks more like a spec than a valid SO question! We dont work from specs, we help you fix specific pieces of code you are having problems with

Comment: AFAIK code returning the variable would be even better

Comment: So far I was trying to make some kind of for/if or foreach functions with usage of array_seach/array_column or if/in array, sadly without success. As far as var_export goes, that unleash uncontrollable string of data that is unreadable and Nette does not like it very much, so as far as I worked with this project I used dump($foo) every time.

Answer (score 0):

So after few hours of digging I was amazed how easily it can by done

```
  // searching for all unique supplier_id
  $uniqueID = array();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item['product']['supplier_id'], $uniqueID)) {
    array_push($uniqueID, $item['id'] = $item['product']['supplier_id']);
    }
  }
  // visual check of all unique *supplier_id*
  dump($uniqueID);

  // creation of array where I'm going to insert all necessary data
  foreach ($uniqueID as $array) {
    $defined_array = [];

    // visual check for debugging purposes
    dump("start");

    // creating multiarray for every unique *supplier_id* and inserting data
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      if($item['product']['supplier_id'] == $array) {
        $defined_array[] = $item;            
      }
    }

    // final check of all arrays + debug check for end -- 
    // at the end this block is replaced by *create_order* code
        foreach ($defined_array as $array) {
            dump($array);
        }
        dump("end");      
    }
```

At the end I hope it will help to someone at least.